# Email Composer with Attributed String

Tags: ios, swift, email, nsattributedstring

How can I send attributed string via Email?

```
mailComposerVC.setMessageBody(textView.attributedString, isHTML: false)
```

Comment: Allow HTML (`isHTML:true`), and you can convert a `NSAttributedString` to "HTML text".

Comment: I'm getting error that I cannot convert NSAttributedSrtring to String

Comment: The `setMessageBody` method does not accept an `NSAttributedString`, you will need to pass a `NSString`. This `NSString` can contain HTML tags.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have convert your Attributed string to HTML string. Use following code to generate html string.

```
        do {
        let data = try string.dataFromRange(NSMakeRange(0, string.length), documentAttributes: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute : NSHTMLTextDocumentType])
        let htmlString = String(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    }catch {

    }
```

Use generated html string as

```
mailComposerVC.setMessageBody(htmlString, isHTML: true)
```

Answer (score 3):

Thanks guys, this is how it's done:

```
    var cookedString : String!
    let attributeStrung = myTextView.attributedText

    let documentAttributes = [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType]
    do
    {
        let htmlData = try attributeStrung.dataFromRange(NSMakeRange(0, attributeStrung.length), documentAttributes: documentAttributes)
        if let htmlString = String(data: htmlData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        {
            cookedString = htmlString
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        print("error creating HTML from Attributed String")
    }

    let mailComposerVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
    mailComposerVC.mailComposeDelegate = self
    mailComposerVC.setMessageBody(cookedString, isHTML: true)
```

Answer (score 1):

Updated to swift 5 Xcode 12.1

```
var cookedString : String!
let attributeString = myTextView.attributedText

    let documentAttributes = [NSAttributedString.DocumentAttributeKey.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html]
        do
        {
            let htmlData = try attributeString!.data(from: NSMakeRange(0, attributeStrung!.length), documentAttributes: documentAttributes)
            if let htmlString = String(data: htmlData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
            {
                cookedString = htmlString
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            print("error creating HTML from Attributed String")
        } let mailComposerVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
mailComposerVC.mailComposeDelegate = self
mailComposerVC.setMessageBody(cookedString, isHTML: true)
```