# HTML code with special characters \n \r, how to display properly

Tags: html, texttemplate

I`m a newbie in programming, and I have to work with realy old code (2004). In my program I have e-mail message generator which gives me code like this:

```
<html>\r\n<body>\r\n<div id=\"start\">\r\n\t<table border=\"0\" style=\"font-family:Arial; font-size:11pt; color:#000000; border: 1px solid black;\">\r\n\t\t<tr>\r\n\t\t\t
<td colspan=\"3\" style=\"border-bottom: 1px solid black;\" align=\"center\">\r\n\t\t\t\t<i>Message generated by system, 02/10/2019 09:21:08</i>\r\n\t\t\t
</td>\r\n\t\t</tr>  \r\n\t\t<tr>\r\n\t\t\t<td valign=\"top\" width=\"100\" style=\"border-bottom: 1px solid black;\" align=\"right\">\r\n\t\t\t\tTemat:\r\n\t\t\t</td><td width=
\"400\" style=\"border-bottom: 1px solid black;\" align=\"left\">\r\n\t\t\t\t<b>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t99/K/1654417/02<br/> \r\n\t\t\t\t\t<a href=\"/Order/OrderView/OrderView.aspx?qsp=Z
HKF14WMj10PT2OzbqmOMNHGlam2===sla==s2===sla==0VxOF8eK1SJu4=\">Warsztat sieciowy 1</a><br/>\r\n\t\t\t\t\tWYKONANIE ZLECENIA<br>\r\n\t\t\t\t</b>\r\n\t\t\t</td>\r\n\t\t\t<td width
=\"400\" style=\"border-bottom: 1px solid black;\" align=\"center\" valign=\"top\">\r\n\t\t\t\t<table>
```

And when I save this text as index.html I have site like below:
[image]

When I send email will the customer see special characters like in HTML page?

Comment: Why don't you try it out by sending an email to yourself? ;-) It actually depends on how the program will handle the string before submission. If it parses the line breaks and tabs, then no, they won't be visible in the mail client. But if not, they are simply text, and in that case of course they will be displayed (unless the receiving client performs some parsing magic on its own, which would actually be a bad mail client, tampering with the message content...).

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35843883/email-composer-with-attributed-string